# CSS calc() and CSS Variables (Decimals and Division)

Tags: html, css, css-variables

So I've been experimenting with CSS variables just to work with basic math, and I have the following JSFiddle (replication of code below): 
http://jsfiddle.net/eliseo_d/ry792Lnp/7/

```css
:root {
  --a: 51;
  --b: 32;
}

#test_add:before {
  color: red;
  counter-reset: add_res calc(var(--a) + var(--b));
  content: counter(add_res);
}

#test_sub:before {
  color: blue;
  counter-reset: sub_res calc(var(--a) - var(--b));
  content: counter(sub_res);
}

#test_mul:before {
  color: orange;
  counter-reset: mul_res calc(var(--a) * var(--b));
  content: counter(mul_res);
}

#test_div:before {
  color: green;
  counter-reset: div_res calc(var(--a) / var(--b));
  content: counter(div_res);
}
```

```html
<div id="test_add"></div>
<div id="test_sub"></div>
<div id="test_mul"></div>
<div id="test_div"></div>
```

The results for the addition, subtraction and multiplication DIVs is correct, but I've had trouble getting the division DIV to work. Is there some special thing that must be done with the CSS variables for this to work?

Also, if I were to replace 51 with 5.1 and 32 with 3.2, the results for all of them also end up as zero... Is there any way that CSS Variables can work with decimals? **Please note: I don't want to work with SASS or LESS or any other preprocessor here, I'm trying to investigate the potential I have with CSS variables on their own...**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think the issue is not with variable here or calc. calc handle perfectly float but your are using counter here which work with only integers

Comment: @TemaniAfif, if calc handles floats without issue, shouldn't I be getting 1 for the division? `INT(51/32) = 1` if my math isn't mistaken?

Comment: here you assume that calc should round the number which is not trivial .. calc will return the reuslt as a float and counter will not accept it ... here is an example where I used the value within border : http://jsfiddle.net/ry792Lnp/13/ check the computed style to see that calc return the correct values (1.594) and it works with border because it accepts float

Comment: ***counter*** `content` can only be of type `integer` thus when doing a division, it might be a float, and will print `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TemaniAfif is right: the problem here is that `calc` division (at least in August 2018) always returns a float, and `counter-reset` (as well as many other CSS properties) only works with integer values. There's an [issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2337) on csswg-drafts for that:

> Right now, `calc()` carefully tracks whether a numeric expression (no
>   units or %s) is guaranteed to resolve to an integer, or might resolve
>   to a more general number. This allows it to be used in places like
>   z-index safely.
>
> However, it excludes some expressions that would be integral if
>   evaluated - for example, **any division makes it non-integral**, even in
>   an expression like `calc(4 / 2)`.

Essentially, this proposal was accepted, but it seems to be not implemented in browsers - yet. For example, [the relevant Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=874332) (which, to be precise, is about inability to use calc division result as param of CSS Grid) has been opened just two weeks ago.

Comment: That's a bit suckworthy, but glad that there's been some discussion into resolving this... Any idea when this will be implemented?

Comment: So, is there any way to display the values of var()'s in content, or will I have to settle for the counter methodology?

Comment: It's not about `var`, it's about division; even if you put `calc(4/2)`, the result is still float, and counter is still 0.

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio actually no way, here is a illustration of some cases : https://codepen.io/textmonster404/pen/PeMmqO?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --a: 51;
  --b: 32;
}

#test_add:before {
  color: red;
  counter-reset: add_res calc(var(--a) + var(--b));
  content: counter(add_res);
}

#test_sub:before {
  color: blue;
  counter-reset: sub_res calc(var(--a) - var(--b));
  content: counter(sub_res);
}

#test_mul:before {
  color: orange;
  counter-reset: mul_res calc(var(--a) * var(--b));
  content: counter(mul_res);
}

#test_div:before {
  color: green;
  counter-reset: div_res calc(var(--a) / var(--b));
  content: counter(div_res);
}
```

```html
<div id="test_add"></div>
<div id="test_sub"></div>
<div id="test_mul"></div>
<div id="test_div"></div>
```